# TinyTable sorter gets an undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am attempting to use the TinyTableV3 JQuery plugin; however, I keep getting an 'undefined' does not exist error. Then, when clicking the columns for sorting I get the 'sorter' does not exist error. This indicates an initialization issue, but as there seems to be no readme for this plugin, I'm not certain where it might be going wrong. Code below. Help?

```
<html>
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/TinyTableV3/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sorter;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter', 'listtbl', {
                headclass: 'head',
                ascclass: 'asc',
                descclass: 'desc',
                evenclass: 'evenrow',
                oddclass: 'oddrow',
                evenselclass: 'evenselected',
                oddselclass: 'oddselected',
                paginate: false,
                size: 100,
                sortcolumn: 1,
                sortdir: 1,
                init: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <table id="listtbl" class="listtbl">
            <tr>
                <th>number</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>address</th>
                <th>comment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>97</td>
                <td>bob</td>
                <td>666 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>912</td>
                <td>daisy</td>
                <td>856 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>john</td>
                <td>666 sooome</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>365</td>
                <td>kindle</td>
                <td>66 mantimed</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>ishmael</td>
                <td>12 diddles</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>234</td>
                <td>hoppy</td>
                <td>666 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>snaps</td>
                <td>666 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>pickpic</td>
                <td>666 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>hahazabamadan</td>
                <td>666 mantime</td>
                <td>this is a comment</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

tiny table v3 found at http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/11/advanced-javascript-table-sorter/

Comment: Could you supply a http://jsfiddle.net demonstration?

Comment: I'm not sure how, given that this is a plugin added from a seperated file.

Comment: If you are not able to establish this file as a url linked with script tag, just copy its contents and paste them in the first line of javascript section in jsfiddle.

Comment: you know your HTML is out of order?  Your last tag is the body closing tag.. then your head closing tag?

Comment: @wirey Oops, bad copying. I've fixed it above.

Comment: try renaming your `var tinytable` to `var sorter` - that seemed to be the issue in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cP6qv/

Comment: @wirey Just noticed the tbody and thead tags. Those and the sorted bit fixed everything. Please submit as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your `var tinytable` to `var sorter` - that seemed to be the issue in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cP6qv/

Also your html was was mixed up - your body tag was inside your head tag. etc..

You should also use  tags to wrap your  and  to wrap your table body